# 14.10 - software updater - Package operation failed - Unable to udpate any apt packages - Completely blocked

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-center

I am using 14.10 Ubuntu. Software updater fails with following error:

> Package operation failed

From terminal, tried to do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This gives following error :

```
➜  ~  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade                  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcdr-0.1-1 libcgmanager0:i386 libcmis-0.4-4 libfox-1.6-0 libmspub-0.1-1 libvisio-0.1-1 xarchiver
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cgmanager git git-core git-man gnome-session gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common libapache2-mod-php5 libblkid1 libcgmanager0 libcgmanager0:i386 libmount1 libsmartcols1
  libunity-settings-daemon1 libuuid1 libuuid1:i386 openjdk-7-jre:i386 openjdk-7-jre-headless:i386 php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-gd php5-mysql php5-readline ubuntu-session
  unity-settings-daemon usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk uuid-runtime
29 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/53.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 16.4 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up util-linux (2.25.1-3ubuntu4.1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'sav-web' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'sav-protect' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'sav-rms' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service minidlna and sav-web if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service sav-web at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service minidlna at depth 1
insserv: Stopping sav-web depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Stopping sav-protect depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Stopping sav-rms depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It is a total blocker. I am unable to install/update/remove any apt package now.  Root cause seem to be (my guess):

```
insserv: warning: script 'sav-web' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'sav-protect' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'sav-rms' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service minidlna and sav-web if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service sav-web at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service minidlna at depth 1
insserv: Stopping sav-web depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Stopping sav-protect depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Stopping sav-rms depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
```

Tried the following, which also gives the same output:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Tried

```
➜  ~  sudo dpkg --configure -a                  
Setting up ntp (1:4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu2.14.10.3) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: warning: script 'sav-web' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'sav-protect' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'sav-rms' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service minidlna and sav-web if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service sav-web at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service minidlna at depth 1
insserv: Stopping sav-web depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Stopping sav-protect depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Stopping sav-rms depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package ntp (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up mongodb-server (1:2.6.3-0ubuntu5) ...
insserv: warning: script 'sav-web' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'sav-protect' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'sav-rms' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service minidlna and sav-web if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service sav-web at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service minidlna at depth 1
insserv: Stopping sav-web depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Stopping sav-protect depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Stopping sav-rms depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up util-linux (2.25.1-3ubuntu4.1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'sav-web' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'sav-protect' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'sav-rms' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service minidlna and sav-web if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service sav-web at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service minidlna at depth 1
insserv: Stopping sav-web depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Stopping sav-protect depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Stopping sav-rms depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up apport (2.14.7-0ubuntu8.4) ...
insserv: warning: script 'sav-web' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'sav-protect' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'sav-rms' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service minidlna and sav-web if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service sav-web at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service minidlna at depth 1
insserv: Stopping sav-web depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Stopping sav-protect depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Stopping sav-rms depends on minidlna and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package apport (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport-gtk:
 apport-gtk depends on apport (>= 0.41); however:
  Package apport is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apport-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ntp
 mongodb-server
 util-linux
 apport
 apport-gtk
```

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that the `sav-*` scripts mentioned in your output seem to be missing a LSB-header. If that is some Sophos Antivirus stuff, better ask Sophos about it. If all else fails, try to add the LSB tags manually to `/etc/init.d/sav-web` and the other two.

Comment: LSB tags are just warnings. It is not causing the blocker.   "There is a loop between service minidlna and sav-web if stopped" - This is causing the issue. I am not sure how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Tracing back to conflict between minidlna and sophos Anti virus (still don't know why they go in a loop while apt update), [Uninstalled sophos](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/26531.aspx) using

```
sudo sh /opt/sophos-av/uninstall.sh
```

Now I am able to proceed. Hope it helps some one else facing this issue.